# Sum/count with a where/if statement to find existing value

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm building a table to use for weekly reports but I'm starting with queries to get an idea of the data first.

Below I have my main query, which is working for my main totals currently, but my existing 'Total' columns need a partner column which will display a different total. Basically, this is all in relation to phone calls, so currently I have phone totals (total calls, total missed, total inbound, total outbound) but I need an additional column for each that counts the amount of calls that were to/from known numbers in our database.

I have a table called `ambition.ambition_customer_data` with a field called `phone_number`. So, if you look about 8 lines down in my query I need to get a sum or count for numbers where `calledpartyno = ambition_customer_data.phone_number OR finallycalledpartyno = ambition_customer_data.phone_number` if that makes sense.

For the other columns, I'll need to do the same but I will have to base it on the `legtype` column seen below, but If I have an idea of how to do this first I can apply it to those. I was hoping I could do a SUM(WHERE calledpartyno IN (select phone_number from ambition_customer_data)) but that doesn't seem to work.

I currently have an incomplete IF statement. Any tips on the best way I can do this?

```
SELECT 
    u.firstn
    , u.lastn
    , c.extension
    , SUM(IF(LEGTYPE1 = 1, 1, 0)) +                   -- outbound calls
            SUM(IF(LEGTYPE1 = 2, 1, 0) AND ANSWERED = 1) +  -- inbound calls
            SUM(IF(Answered = 1, 0, 1))  AS Total_Calls

    , sum(if calledpartyno =) /*HERE IS MY ISSUE CURRENTLY*/

    , sum(if(Answered = 1,0,1)) AS Total_Missed

    , sum(if(LEGTYPE1 = 2,1,0) and ANSWERED = 1) AS Total_Recieved

    , sum(if(LEGTYPE1 = 1,1,0)) AS Total_Outbound

    , round(sum(Duration) / 60,2) AS Total_Talk_Time_minutes

    , sum(if(Answered = 1,0,1)) / (SUM(IF(LEGTYPE1 = 1, 1, 0)) +                   -- outbound calls
            SUM(IF(LEGTYPE1 = 2, 1, 0) AND ANSWERED = 1) +  -- inbound calls
            SUM(IF(Answered = 1, 0, 1)))  * 100 AS Percentage_Missed




      FROM ambition.session a
      INNER JOIN ambition.callsummary b
            ON a.NOTABLECALLID = b.NOTABLECALLID
      INNER join ambition.mxuser c
            ON a.RESPONSIBLEUSEREXTENSIONID = c.EXTENSIONID
      INNER join jackson_id.users u
            on c.extension = u.extension
      WHERE b.ts between curdate() - interval 5 day and now()
      AND c.extension IN (7276,7314,7295,7306,7357,7200,7218,7247,7331,7255,7330,7000,7215,7240,7358,7312)
      group by c.extension;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for something like this.

SUM(CASE WHEN **CONDITION_HERE** THEN **COLUMN_TO_SELECT** END) AS `SELECTION_NAME`